# Enclose fields field separators in quotes

Tags: awk

We are using oracle's sqlldr to load data files created by a third party. The data files vary in size and some are very large.

The fields of the data file are separated by "|"

Example: `field1|field2|field3|field4|field5`

`field3` could be:

- empty
- single value
- `value1|value2|value3`

I need to enclose `field3` with quotes if it contains `|.`

I've made a shell script to do this, but it is a bit slow - about 16 minutes to process a file with 47,000,000 lines.

I was thinking of doing it in awk, but I'm not that familiar with the syntax and deadlines don't permit learning/developing/debugging.

Would it be significantly faster in awk?

Is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Given the input: `a|b|c|d|e|f|g`, how can you tell if the third field is `c`, or `c|d|e`?

Comment: So would `field1|field2|value1|value2|value3|field4|field5` become `field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry I forgot to mention that it is known that there are 5 fields, hence field 3 is what's between field2 and field4

Comment: @dawg Yes, exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|value1|value2|field4|field5
field1|field2|value1|value2|value3|field4|field5
```

You can use this awk:

```
awk  '  BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}        # sep fields on |
        NF<=5{print; next}       # if there are <=5, we are done with line
        {s=$1 OFS $2 OFS "\""    # form first 2 fields + "
        # now loop through the extra fields adding to string after quote:
        for (i=3;i<=NF-5+3;i++) s=(i<NF-5+3) ? s $i OFS : s $i
        s=s "\"" OFS $(NF-5+4) OFS $(NF)   # finish the string
        print s                            # then print it
        }' file
```

Prints:

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
```

And yes -- this would be significantly faster with awk vs just the shell.

---

If you want a one liner, I would use perl this way:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lpE  's/^([^|]+\|[^|]+\|)(.*)(\|[^|]+\|[^|]+)$/\1"\2"\3/ if scalar @F!=5' file
```

Same output.

Comment: Wow! Looks great - I'll look at it when I connect to work tonight. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this and it (awk, not perl) is the only solution that works. Some of the others worked as well, except they put double quotes on all third fields whether there were extra "|"'s or not.
Thanks very much @dawg!!!
And thanks to all for the unexpectedly quick responses!

Comment: Now I'll spend a week or so trying to understand how the awk works ;o)

Comment: @philb the solution I posted doesn't put double quotes around all third fields. Can you tell me in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: @ed-morton
Sorry - my comment was vague. I said "some" - but not yours. Yours worked as well. I flagged this as a solution because somehow I only saw your answer after I saw this one...

Comment: I was responding to your statement that this solution "is the only solution that works". You saw my answer after this one because I answered after this one, that's all. Hopefully you accepted the answer you're going to use rather than the first answer you got but no worries either way, I was just curious if mine had a problem after seeing [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382737/enclose-fields-field-separators-in-quotes/65383282?noredirect=1#comment115615383_65383110), thanks for letting me know it doesn't.

Comment: @philb: Thanks for accepting! I added comments to help you understand the awk...

Answer (score 3):

With any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NF>5{sub(/^([^|]*\|){2}/,"&\""); sub(/(\|[^|]*){2}$/,"\"&")} 1' file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
```

Alternatives:

With a sed that has `-E` to enable EREs (e.g. GNU and BSD/OSX sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/^(([^|]*\|){2})(.*\|.*)((\|[^|]*){2})/\1"\3"\4/' file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/^\(\([^|]*|\)\{2\}\)\(.*|.*\)\(\(|[^|]*\)\{2\}\)/\1"\3"\4/' file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
```

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/^(([^|]*\|){2})(.*\|.*)((\|[^|]*){2})$/,"\\1\"\\3\"\\4",1)} 1' file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
```

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^(([^|]*\|){2})(.*\|.*)((\|[^|]*){2})$/,a){$0=a[1] "\"" a[3] "\"" a[4]} 1' file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
```

The above were run against the sample input file [created by @dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65383110/1745001):

```
$ cat file
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|value1|value2|field4|field5
field1|field2|value1|value2|value3|field4|field5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner using [`splice`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice), which runs for ~1.5 min on 47e6 lines:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane '@first = splice @F, 0, 2; @last = splice @F, -2, 2; print join "|", @first, ( @F > 1 ? q{"} . ( join "|", @F ) . q{"} : @F ), @last;' in_file
```

Input:

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|val1|val2|val3|field4|field5
```

Output:

```
field1|field2|"field3"|field4|field5
field1|field2|""|field4|field5
field1|field2|"val1|val2|val3"|field4|field5
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/[|]/'` : Split into `@F` on `|`, rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

**Benchmark:**

```
# Make input file with 47e6 lines:

perl -le '
$s = 
"field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|val1|val2|val3|field4|field5";
print $s for 1..15_666_667;
' > in_file.txt

wc -l in_file.txt
# 47_000_001

time perl -F'[|]' -lane '@first = splice @F, 0, 2; @last = splice @F, -2, 2; print join "|", @first, ( @F > 1 ? q{"} . ( join "|", @F ) . q{"} : @F ), @last;' in_file.txt > out_file.txt
```

Runs for a median of 1 min 31 sec. Measured 3 times using perl 5, version 30, subversion 3 (v5.30.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level, running on MacBook Pro, macOS 10.14.6.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk

```
$ cat philb2
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|value1|value2|field4|field5
field1|field2|value1|value2|value3|field4|field5
$ awk -F"|" ' NF==5{print; next} {OFS="|"; v1=$(NF);v2=$(NF-1);f1=$1;f2=$2;$1=$2=""; m=substr($0,3,length($0)-length(v1 v2)-4); print f1,f2,"\"" m "\"",v2,v1; } ' philb2
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
field1|field2||field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
$
```

Comment: Thanks, but field 3 should not be in quotes if there are no delimiters in it.

Comment: @philb.. I just updated the answer.. could you pls check.

Comment: Didn't work (sorry - not crazy about the formatting syntax...):  
`  
IN:  
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5  
field1|field2||field4|field5  
field1|field2|value1|value2|field4|field5  
field1|field2|value1|value2|value3|field4|field5  
OUT:  
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5|field2|"field3"|field4|field5  
field1|field2||field4|field5|field2|""|field4|field5  
field1|field2|"value1|value2"|field4|field5  
field1|field2|"value1|value2|value3"|field4|field5
`

Comment: @philb..sorry..messed up.. can you check my update2.. if that is fine.. I'll keep that alone in the answer